# How to show the exact number of likes in the "Like Button"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

How do I show the exact number of likes in the "Like Button" to layout button_count?
For example "13.000 likes". How do I show the full number of likes?

Answer (score 5):

It's very simply, you can do it via Graph API URL as, for eg.

http://graph.facebook.com/http://digimantra.com

Here is the function to do it -

```
function fb_fan_count($facebook_name){
    // Example: https://graph.facebook.com/digimantra
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$facebook_name));
    echo $data->likes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ping graph api to get real count

http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://current.addr/current/url.php