# Facebook Like button - show actual numbers?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I am currently using the Facebook like button on a website and when the numbers get quite high, the number becomes truncated with a 'k' for thousand or 'm' for million.

Rather than displaying '1m', is there anyway to display the actual number i.e. 1,000,543.

The documentation and demo seems to show a raw number for the standard layout but there is no mention of this in the attributes section or how to action it for the button_count layout.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/7324769/2089361,

use facebook **graph API**:
query http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.facebook.com/thedoors, get JSON string in response, parse it and here's the actual likes count.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks and sorry for not picking up the earlier question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fb_like_count($facebook_name){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$facebook_name));
    echo $data->likes;
}
```

Will `echo` the number of likes. `$facebook_name` is the `url` of the page.